# NHibernate: One-To-One-Relationship not correctly updating

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I want to map two types, `ConnectionProfile` to `ConnectionType`. In my `ConnectionProfile` I have:

```cs
public virtual ConnectionType ConnectionType { get; set; }
```

in my `ConnectionType` I have:

```cs
public virtual ConnectionProfile ConnectionProfile { get; set; }
```

My mappings are:

```cs
// ConnectionProfile
HasOne(x => x.ConnectionType).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
// ConnectionType
References(x => x.ConnectionProfile);
```

This works when I create a new `ConnectionProfile` and `SaveOrUpdate` it. The connection type is correctly created and saved.

However, when I load the `ConnectionProfile`, create a new `ConnectionType`, assign it (and yes, I also assign the other side) and `SaveOrUpdateAsync` the connection profile again, upon re-loading it, it still has the old profile associated.

I cannot fill the generated `ConnectionType` proxy with the new values, I have to create a new object, because I am using subclasses.

## Followup 1

On other examples here on SO, I found a mapping like this:

```cs
// ConnectionProfile
HasOne(x => x.ConnectionType).PropertyRef(nameof(ConnectionType.ConnectionProfile)).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
// ConnectionType
References(x => x.ConnectionProfile).Unique();
```

However, for this to work, I need two transactions:

```cs
using(var txn = session.BeginTransaction()) {
    // Update all the other stuff here
    p.ConnectionType = null;
    await session.SaveOrUpdateAsync(p);
    await txn.CommitAsync();
}
using(var txn = session.BeginTransaction()) {
    var ct = CreateMyCoolConnectionType();
    p.ConnectionType = ct;
    ct.ConnectionProfile = p;
    await session.SaveOrUpdateAsync(p);
    await txn.CommitAsync();
}
```

When I do everything in a single transaction, upon committing, I get:

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: ConnectionType.ConnectionProfile_id
```

I thought the `Cascade` option should take care of this? Or is this the way it has to be done?

Comment: Try to remove `SaveOrUpdateAsync ` call (simply `Commit` transaction after modifications) for the case `when I load the ConnectionProfile, create a new ConnectionType, assign it`

Comment: This gives me `UNIQUE constraint failed: ConnectionType.ConnectionProfile_id`, too

Comment: Then it seems you need to do it in 2 steps as in your follow-up. You can still make it in one transaction by calling `session.FlushAsync()` after setting `ConnectionType`  to null

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as an answer so I can accept it, if no other user has a better solution.

User Roman Artiukhin led me to a solution where I can use a single transaction by using `Flush`. It still needs to be done in two steps which leaves me worried that in this very moment another instance might query the database and get an inconsistent state.

In the application it doesn't matter that much as the user can then always do the operation again without any dangers, but there should be some method like a "Soft Commit".

My workaround now looks like this:

```cs
using(var txn = session.BeginTransaction()) {
    // Update all the other stuff here
    p.ConnectionType = null;
    await session.FlushAsync();
    var ct = CreateMyCoolConnectionType();
    p.ConnectionType = ct;
    ct.ConnectionProfile = p;
    await txn.CommitAsync();
}
```

A better way would be to temporarily turn off the uniqueness check until the txn was committed, and then turn it on again. However since it is database dependent how it is done, I want to refrain from this.